# How to build Apple's GCC on Linux/Windows?

Tags: ios, iphone, gcc

I don't have a Mac, but I have an iPhone. I want to develop applications for iPhone.
After some research I think I need just the headers and library from the free SDK, and a GCC build that supports ARM/Mach-O.
Apple released the code for GCC used in the iPhone SDK (they had to), So I think if I could build it on Windows or Linux, I can use it with the headers and libs from the SDK to develop iPhone apps.

I can then install the app on any Jailbroken iPhone.

How to build it on any non Apple machine?

Comment: Are you doing this just for fun, or are you actually trying to do something useful? If the latter, and you won't go the official way, have you considered using VMWare?

Comment: Apple will jettison GCC in Xcode. You should really use the LLVM compiler instead. And don't try to build it on a windows or linux machine. Go buy a Mac.

Answer (score 5):

Look into winchain - this tool builds the iphone chain on windows allowing you to compile iphone apps on windows:

http://code.google.com/p/winchain/wiki/HowToUse

-Adam

Comment: I downloaded it, I didn't try it yet.
But it looks like a pre-Build Tool Chain, and it's a not maintained project (2007)

I want to know how to build the ToolChain from the source on Windows or Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Check [iOS Build Environment for Windows](http://www.pmbaty.com/iosbuildenv/). From what I see it uses llvm compiler and is frequently updated. You can use it with your own editor or use a stand alone wizard to generate a Visual Studio project (works with both VC++ and VC++ express). The only disadvantage is that it has a demo version and requires donation for full version. However I expect you would be able to use the toolchain included in the demo without a problem.

I've downloaded the demo and played along with my own project and samples provided. It compiles just fine. Unfortunately I'm unable to test the results on my devices since none of them is currently jailbroken.